# Insert real-time data to MySQL database using C language

Tags: mysql, c, raspberry-pi2

I can read temperature and humidity using sensor with 
**Raspberry Pi 2** using `C`. The problem is when I execute my code, data only display on the screen but not be saved in the database. But I want to save them into my **MySQL** database. How can I do it?

Comment: share the `mysql` portion of your code that you have tried so far. This will help other to understand where it went wrong.

Comment: I don't know how to insert data to mysql in C so I haven't written mysql portion yet

Comment: then please follow these two answeres [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162725/accessing-mysql-database-from-c) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453168/c-program-mysql-connection) and do some study. You will get this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's very useful with me.